# Dependency Convergence: Bouncycastle in different versions on different level of dependency

Tags: maven, bouncycastle

In my Maven-Project I'm using a dependency which uses bouncycastle in two different versions on different levels of this dependency and I need the new version, but not the old one (because it provides a dependency convergence error). I can't exclude a specific version and I can't change the pom of the dependency sadly.

```
+-MyProject:3.4.0
  +-DependencyA1:1.3.0
    +-DependencyA2:10.0.2
      +-DependencyA3:17.0.1
        +-DependencyA4:17.0.1
          +-org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68

+-MyProject:3.4.0
  +-DependencyA1:1.3.0
    +-DependencyA2:10.0.2
      +-DependencyA3:17.0.1
        +-org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.62
```

I tried providing bouncycastle with scope "provided" in a specific version, but this just led to more dependency convergences.

Comment: Define a dependencyManagement in your project with the appropriate version you would like to choose.

Comment: I did that and I didn't receive a dependency convergence error anymore. But my project says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECNamedCurveSpec

Comment: That you have a problem because one of your project is using a class which does not exists in a newer version. Which looks like a breaking change in bouncycastle.. which you can not prevent. So from my point of view the only way would be to change the existing projects or you might need to upgrade a version which would work for both projects example (1.65 just a guess!Depending in which version the change has been done; Read the release notes of bouncycastle)...